# Сборка C# проекта через .Net Core SDK 1.1.3 через cmd

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, .net-core, csproj

Недавно начал курс по Web ,а для сборки задания нужен .Net Core SDK 1.1.3 .
Выдает либо не та версия .Net Core ,либо невозможное значение пути в файле SDK(путь к моему проекту ,который я хочу собрать).
Window 7

Могу скинуть скрины...
Благодарю...

Comment: Так а версия та? Что dotnet --info показывает? И почему версия SDK такая старая, может поновее возьмете?

Comment: я пробовал 2 и 3 версию.Если что вот курс https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV247x+3T2018/courseware/dc1dc4d1eebe45248551e9368730c0f4/4f24e594dd55421d97a7146022f6f806/?child=last